# jquery replaceWith for special html character

Tags: jquery, html

On my page I have a star using:

```
    <div class="favorite">&#9734 </div>
```

On hover, I want to replace it with a filled in star. Here's the Jquery code I wrote:

```
    $(".favorite").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).replaceWith("&#9733;");
        },
        function(){

        }
    );
```

However, it never seems to work. This way it just shows me the text. Removing the quotes, it breaks. Any suggestions would help! I understand I could do this with a png but I'd rather not --- one less thing I need to have. Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5CWJJ/

Comment: It worked http://jsfiddle.net/LAnZw/

Comment: Dont forget to link the JQuery library/CDN.

Comment: Argh, seems to work now.... related question, how do I get it to go back when I mouse out? changing the second function to:  $(this).replaceWith("&#9734;"); doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Just as an explanation: `replaceWith` literally *replaces* the element with the new content you pass as argument. Thus, if you replace the `div` element with the HTML entity, the element doesn't exist anymore afterwards, hence no further events are triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use html() in jquery:

```
$(".favorite").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).html("&#9733;");
        },
        function(){
             $(this).html("&#9734;");
        }
    );
```